# CentOS: How to install latest emacs version with YUM

Tags: installation, emacs, centos, yum

OS: CentOS release 4.6 (Final)

I am trying to install the latest emacs which is listed [on their website](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) as being v24.3.
However, when I try to install with YUM the version is 21.3-19 which is from 10 years ago.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use old OS (CentOS) and emacs-21.3-19 is the latest version that exists in CentOS 4.6 repositories. Try to find more fresh version [here](http://fr.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=emacs&submit=Search%20...), or another custom repository, or compile latest emacs version from sources.

Comment: is there a way to add the lates version to the repositories in order to use YUM?

Comment: It is big headache to support repositories for old OS. Different versions of software have different dependencies. I think it almost impossible. Only if you have your personal repository.

Comment: So does that mean I cannot use YUM? I need to compile from source?

Comment: .........Yep. :(